# Container width + margin-left does not show all images while sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have the following HTML code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  calculate_width();

  $('#moveleft').click(function() {
    var loga = $('#marki #loga');

    if ($('#marki .container').width() + Math.abs(parseInt(loga.css('margin-left'))) < loga.width()) {
      loga.animate({
        'margin-left': "-=100px"
      });
    }
  });
  $('#moveright').click(function() {
    var loga = $('#marki #loga');

    if (parseInt(loga.css('margin-left')) < 0) {
      loga.animate({
        'margin-left': "+=100px"
      });
    }
  });
});

function calculate_width() {
  var szerokosc = 0;

  $('#loga a img').each(function() {
    szerokosc += $(this).outerWidth(true);
  });
  $('#marki #loga').width(szerokosc);
}
```

```css
#marki .container {
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
}

#marki #loga {
    font-size: 0px;
}

#marki a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 30px 0 0;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#marki a:last-of-type {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="marki">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="loga">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
      </a>
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="padding:20px;">
  <button id="moveright" style="float:left;"><<</button>
  <button id="moveleft" style="float:right;">>></button>
</div>
```

As you can see, when I click `>>` button `$('#marki #loga')` gets 'margin-left' property to `-+ 100px`.

But I want to achieve, that I can scroll until the last image. But the calculation:
`$('#marki .container').width() + Math.abs(parseInt(loga.css('margin-left'))) < loga.width()`
is false when there are three images left to show.

What I'm calculating wrong? The list of images is getting dynamically, so I can't use the const width of images.

Comment: Please adjust the image's height and width according to the size you are using

Comment: @Swellar the width and height are also dynamically, they have not constant values. This sliding should work for any combinations.

Comment: I see. Anyway, you can re-edit if my edit is wrong

Comment: @Swellar, I forgot to add my css code. Just edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you want to *stop scrolling when the `loga` div's right side has reached the container right side*.
[image: Here is a concrete example of what you want to achieve]

In terms of maths, this condition is that the *absolute value of the `margin-left` property* + the container width is equal to the `loga` div, which is exactly what you have done, so this is not the problem here.

The issue is that your `loga` div have a 3400px width, and you have 17 `<a>` blocks with 225px width each. But `17 * 225 = 3825`, which is why you have those missing blocks when the code reach 3400px. There is 425px missing. Just remove the fixed width of the `loga` div should do the trick

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't want to post the answer right now... I'm just editing it to give you a proper answer

Comment: Yes! As you said, that was the actual problem, thank you! :))